# Return list with numeric keys from C#

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

My code is as follows:

```
var aaData = 
    ctx.PaymentRates
        .Where(x => x.ServiceRateCodeId == new Guid("BBCE42CB-56E3-4848-B396-4656CCE3CE96"))
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            Id = x.Id
        }).ToList();
```

It generates the following JSON when converted using `Json(aaData);`:

```
"aaData":[
    {"Id":"ab57fc9d-ffb7-4a12-8c5c-03f36b4ef1fe"},
    {"Id":"4c1e9776-5d64-4054-a9c9-0fc8b8b8e8a1"}
    etc.
]
```

However, I would like to return keys before the values, like so:

```
"aaData":[
    [0] => {"Id":"ab57fc9d-ffb7-4a12-8c5c-03f36b4ef1fe"},
    [1] => {"Id":"4c1e9776-5d64-4054-a9c9-0fc8b8b8e8a1"}
    etc.
]
```

**Edit:** I am not sure of the proper syntax - the point is, I just want numeric keys.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Is your desired format a valid json at all?

Comment: It may not be the exact syntax - I'm just trying to get numeric keys. Feel free to edit the syntax, I can't remember how JSON does it.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin It's just `Json(aaData);`.

Comment: Yep saw that which is why I deleted my comment :)

Comment: why do you need the indexes?

Answer (score 3):

JSON uses *implicit* indexing - meaning the order of elements in an array is preserved, so you can *infer* the "index" from the order of elements when you retrieve them.

If you *need* to include an "index" element, you'll have to make it an attribute of the array element:

```
var aaData = 
    ctx.PaymentRates
        .Where(x => x.ServiceRateCodeId == new Guid("BBCE42CB-56E3-4848-B396-4656CCE3CE96"))
        .Select((x, i) => new 
        {
            Index = i,
            Id = x.Id
        }).ToList();
```

Your JSON should look something like:

```
"aaData":[
    {"Index":"0", "Id":"ab57fc9d-ffb7-4a12-8c5c-03f36b4ef1fe"},
    {"Index":"1", "Id":"4c1e9776-5d64-4054-a9c9-0fc8b8b8e8a1"}
    etc.
]
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a matter of whether it is possible in C# or not, it is more a matter of the fact that JSON has a certain format and the format you would like to achieve is not compliant with JSON.

So in case you would like to achieve a result in such a format you would have to build your own format (but then you would also have to create your own serializers, deserializers, etc - in general quite a lot of hassle).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the index? Here's one way you can get it

```
var counter = 0;
var aaData = 
    ctx.PaymentRates
        .Where(x => x.ServiceRateCodeId == new Guid("BBCE42CB-56E3-4848-B396-4656CCE3CE96"))
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            Index = counter++,
            Id = x.Id
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do; however, this code results in syntax error.

Comment: Sorry I had a ; after counter++, adjusted to a ,

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you wish you would have to use a Dictionary instead of a List. Doing:

```
int idx = 0;
var dict = aaData.ToDictionary(k => "" + idx++);
```

will return provide you with the following valid JSON

```
"aaData":{
    "0" : {"Id":"ab57fc9d-ffb7-4a12-8c5c-03f36b4ef1fe"},
    "1" : {"Id":"4c1e9776-5d64-4054-a9c9-0fc8b8b8e8a1"}
    etc.
}
```

note the fact that the keys are strings that contain numeric values. **Numeric values are not supported as keys**.

Comment: I don't think that's valid JSON either.